# Перебор многомерного списка циклом for

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имеется многомерный список

```
list = [1,2,3,4],[1,3,4,2],[4,3,1,2],.....
```

Необходимо перебрать список по каждому 3-му объекту списка на наличие значения 1.
Вопрос к знатокам - "Как в цикле обратиться к каждому 3-му объекту?" В приведенном примере это будет 4, 2, 2,. При этом, чтобы он прошелся по всем вложенным в список "строкам"?

```
for i in list:
    x = i[?][3]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
_list = [ [1,2,3,4],[1,3,4,2],[4,3,1,2] ]

print([ item[3] for item in _list ])
```

Answer (score 1):

Так как каждый i это обычный список, то очень просто:

```
x = i[3]
```

Answer (score 0):

с интервалом равным 4 проверяем равен ли элемент 1

```
_list = [[1,2,3,4],[1,3,4,2],[4,3,1,2]]
rez = [i==1 for i in sum(_list,[])[3::4]]
```